# How to set multiindex column from existing multiindex column df

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

The objective is to add another multiindex on top of existing multiindex column in Pandas.

I have the impression this can be achieve as below

```
 # Assuming we have an existing multilevel index as below
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['level1'],['level2'],df.columns ])

# Along the pipeline, we would like to append another multiindex on top of it
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Top'],df.columns ])
```

However, the compiler return an error

> NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex

May I know how to fix this issue?

Code to reproduce the above error

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 21, 31],
               'B': [12, 22, 32],
               'C': [13, 23, 33]},
              index=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'])


df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['level1'],['level2'],df.columns ])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Top'],df.columns ])
```

Expected output

```
      Top
      level1        
      level2        
           A   B   C
ONE       11  12  13
TWO       21  22  23
THREE     31  32  33
```

Comment: `df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Top'],['level1'],['level2'],df.columns])`?

Comment: Hi @AnuragDabas, thanks for dropping by. However your suggestion still return the same  error. It is worth to note, the addition of second multi index is occurring down the pipeline. I have edited the OP to clarify about this

Comment: don't use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()` 2 times...run the above code after creating the dataframe

Comment: @balandongiv Are you doing it in the same session?  Anurag's answer should work.  Most likely you are attempting in the same session, so `df.columns` is still a `MultiIndex`.  Basically you can only use any of the default containers in `from_product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df], keys=['Top'], axis='columns')
         Top
      level1
      level2
           A   B   C
ONE       11  12  13
TWO       21  22  23
THREE     31  32  33
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien, thanks for the suggestion. I wonder what if someone would like to append at `lowest` level instead, using your approach

Comment: Like that: `pd.concat([df], keys=['Top'], axis='columns').swaplevel(0, -1, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a dictionary with concat:

```
pd.concat({'Top': df}, axis=1)
```